# Net::FTP unable to connect to some hosts

Tags: perl

I'm not sure what can be wrong here since out of 10 servers, 2 are giving me the error:

> Cannot connect to sun09 : Net::FTP: Bad hostname 'sun09:' at deploy_update.pl line 204.

The weird thing is, the following code extract works inside a loop, and works for some servers, but for the `sun09` server I'm unable to connect.

```
$ftp = Net::FTP->new("$hostname:$ftp_port",  Debug => 0)
or die "Cannot connect to $hostname : $@";
$ftp->login($iLogin,$iPass)
or die "failed ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary()
or die "Cannot set to Binary";
$ftp->delete("/admin/replicate/inbound/$file");
#or warn $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd("/admin/replicate/inbound")
or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->put("$file")
or die "Upload Failed ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
```

This works for 8 of 10 servers but not for `sun08` and `sun09`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$ftp_port` is empty for those hosts; you should omit the colon entirely if you want to use the default port.

Comment: Exact :)
Just verified that our new partners didnt populate the ftp port on our db table.

Thanks for the reply!